# Pfx base encoded string to p12 certificates

Tags: java, pfx, p12

I have my P12 certificates saved on a cloud environment and I am fetching those certificates in Java from an environment variable. Now I getting a PFX base 64 encoded string and password. I want to convert the string back to P12 certificates. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Showing your current code might help readers suggest a good way to add the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the base64 string to a `byte[]`, then make a `ByteArrayInputStream` out of it. Then simply read from it with keystore methods like this:
`KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); ks.load(byteArrInputStream, "password".toCharArray());`